# Why does my table in PHP get populated with table attributes instead of fields (using remote DB for Asterisk CDR)?

Tags: php, mariadb, asterisk

I am creating PHP interface for Asterisk CDR table, but my table created in PHP is not being populated properly.

I was able to successfully save CDR to the remote database, run by XAMPP.

Below I am enclosing the SQL code - automatically created by Asterisk's MariaDB

> ```
> SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"; SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0; START
> TRANSACTION; SET time_zone = "+00:00";
>
> /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
> /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
> /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
> /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
> ```
>
> --
>
> ### -- Database: `cdr_ex`
>
> ---
>
> --
>
> ### -- Table structure for table `cdr`
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE `cdr` (   `calldate` datetime NOT NULL,   `clid`
> varchar(80) NOT NULL,   `src` varchar(80) NOT NULL,   `dst`
> varchar(80) NOT NULL,   `dcontext` varchar(80) NOT NULL,   `channel`
> varchar(80) NOT NULL,   `dstchannel` varchar(80) NOT NULL,   `lastapp`
> varchar(80) NOT NULL,   `lastdata` varchar(80) NOT NULL,   `duration`
> int(11) NOT NULL,   `billsec` int(11) NOT NULL,   `disposition`
> varchar(80) NOT NULL,   `amaflags` int(11) NOT NULL,   `accountcode`
> varchar(80) NOT NULL,   `userfield` varchar(80) NOT NULL,   `uniqueid`
> varchar(32) NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
> ```
>
> --
>
> ### -- Dumping data for table `cdr`
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO `cdr` (`calldate`, `clid`, `src`, `dst`, `dcontext`,
> `channel`, `dstchannel`, `lastapp`, `lastdata`, `duration`, `billsec`,
> `disposition`, `amaflags`, `accountcode`, `userfield`, `uniqueid`)
> VALUES ('2019-04-16 09:43:29', '\"t1\" <110>', '110', 's',
> 'from-sip-external', 'SIP/XXX.XXX.X.XXX-00000000', '', 'Playback',
> 'ss-noservice', 7, 6, 'ANSWERED', 3, '', '', 'XXXXXXXXXX.0');
> ```
>
> --
>
> ### -- Indexes for dumped tables
>
> --
>   -- Indexes for table `cdr`
>
> ```
> -- ALTER TABLE `cdr`   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`uniqueid`); COMMIT;
>
> /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
> /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
> /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
> ```

And this is my PHP code:

```php
<body>

  <h1>CDR</h1> <!-- heading -->

  <div class="mainBody">

  <?php

    $query="SELECT 'calldate','dst','lastapp', 'duration', 'billsec', 'disposition' FROM cdr";
    $cdr = mysqli_query($db,$query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($cdr)>0) //if exist print the table consisting of the all the fields from cdr table
    {
      echo "<table border='1'>
          <tr>
            <th>Call Date</th>
            <th>Destination</th>
            <th>Connection type</th>
            <th>Duration</th>
            <th>Billed time</th>
            <th>Status</th>
          </tr>";
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($cdr))
        {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td><div name='cdate'>" . $row['calldate'] . "</div></td>";
          echo "<td><div name='destination'>" . $row['dst'] . "</div></td>";
          echo "<td><div name='ctype'>" . $row['lastapp'] . "</div></td>";
          echo "<td><div name='cduration'>" . $row['duration'] . "</div></td>";
          echo "<td><div name='btime'>" . $row['billsec'] . "</div></td>";
          echo "<td><div name='cstatus'>" . $row['disposition'] . "</div></td>";
          echo "</tr>";             
        }
        echo "</table>";
      }
      else
      {
        echo '<p style="color:red">Nothing to display</p>';
      }

      $db->close(); //close the db 
    ?>

</body>
```

OUTPUT. Instead of table being populated with the actual content, the table attributes names are being fetched in all the fields. (I cannot include a picture).

Has anybody a clue about what I am doing wrong? Other tables (user created) are being populated properly, so I am guessing the Asterisk table may be protected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you want to get, but acordinly to doc mysqli_fetch_array return array with numeric indexes, not hash.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp

Comment: Hi arheops. Thank you for your reply. I want to get the table content fetched in my PHP table. At this moment instead of the actual values like   '2019-04-16 09:43:29', '\"t1\" <110> ...  my table is being populated with the attributes: ` 'calldate', 'clid'...` So for the table with 5 rows I am getting 5 rows of:  'calldate', 'clid'...

Comment: Your table is okay. You have issue with your code. Please read doc or hire php developer.